# Linux -- Display has red tint

Tags: linux, fedora, display, colors, lxde

My monitor seems to have a slightly reddish tint when using the DVI input (it's a LCD, not a CRT). On the VGA input I can adjust the colors, but not on DVI. On OSX/Windows what I would do is create a custom color profile for that display with changed gamma/etc settings, but I cannot seem to find out how to do this under Linux.

Is there any way to change the color profile under linux (short of buying color calibration hardware and using dispcalgui)?

Comment: Try `xrandr --gamma 1:1:1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typing `xrandr --gamma 1:1:1` will likely fix the problem. This should work on any X11 based display system.

Comment: When I try this, it just gives me the usage and options.

Comment: @John: Read it.

Comment: I read it and re-read it.  I even copy-pasted exactly the command you typed.  I don't get what I'm doing wrong. (I fixed my display, but I would still like to know why the command didn't work.)

Comment: @John: I mean the usage.

Comment: I read and re-read that too, and I still don't get it. :/

Comment: @John: What platform are you using?

Comment: @John let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1064/discussion-between-hello71-and-john)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to alter it via software, such as:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*DP1 3840/600x2160/340+0+0  DP1

$ xrandr --output DP1 --gamma 1:1:1

#or

$ redshift -x -m randr
```

That will try to reset it to the default values, but if another software like `xgamma` ran like this:

```
$ xgamma -rgamma 1.0 -ggamma 0.6949030005552019 -bgamma 0.4310480202110507
```

then the above `xrandr` won't reset it(because xgamma is using `vidmode` not `xrandr` mode, see below), so instead you'd have to use:

```
$ xgamma -gamma 1.0
-> Red  1.000, Green  0.695, Blue  0.431
<- Red  1.000, Green  1.000, Blue  1.000
```

to reset it, or `$ redshift -x -m vidmode` (see below)

It depends which functions each program uses behind the scenes. But the point is, you can use different number values for Red, Green and Blue with such programs and try to remove the red tint.

There's also `redshift` to change the color temperature in Kelvin or the R/G/B gamma colors just like the above two programs:

```
$ redshift -h
Usage: redshift -l LAT:LON -t DAY:NIGHT [OPTIONS...]

Set color temperature of display according to time of day.

  -h            Display this help message
  -v            Verbose output
  -V            Show program version

  -b DAY:NIGHT  Screen brightness to apply (between 0.1 and 1.0)
  -c FILE       Load settings from specified configuration file
  -g R:G:B      Additional gamma correction to apply
  -l LAT:LON    Your current location
  -l PROVIDER   Select provider for automatic location updates
                (Type `list' to see available providers)
  -m METHOD     Method to use to set color temperature
                (Type `list' to see available methods)
  -o            One shot mode (do not continuously adjust color temperature)
  -O TEMP       One shot manual mode (set color temperature)
  -p            Print mode (only print parameters and exit)
  -P            Reset existing gamma ramps before applying new color effect
  -x            Reset mode (remove adjustment from screen)
  -r            Disable fading between color temperatures
  -t DAY:NIGHT  Color temperature to set at daytime/night

The neutral temperature is 6500K. Using this value will not change the color
temperature of the display. Setting the color temperature to a value higher
than this results in more blue light, and setting a lower value will result in
more red light.

Default values:

  Daytime temperature: 6500K
  Night temperature: 4500K

Please report bugs to <https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues>
```

Three ways to set 3000 Kelvin with `redshift`:

```
$ redshift -P -O 3000 -m drm
$ redshift -P -O 3000 -m randr
$ redshift -P -O 3000 -m vidmode
```

and reset the colors to normal:

```
$ redshift -x -m randr
$ redshift -x -m drm
$ redshift -x -m vidmode
```

All three should be used, just in case for example `xgamma` was used which did its changes in `vidmode` and until you reset it in `vidmode` too, you'll still see some color tints.

Or, if you were interested in setting the gamma values to less red (but first reset everything with the above 3 redshift lines):

```
$ redshift -P -O 6500k -g 0.8:1:1
Using method `randr'.
```

(for some reason color temperature must be specified or else you can't use `-g` to set the gamma, with `redshift`)

On Gentoo, here are the packages that own those binaries:

```
Gentoo Package : executable binary  
x11-apps/xrandr: /usr/bin/xrandr  
x11-apps/xgamma: /usr/bin/xgamma  
x11-misc/redshift: /usr/bin/redshift
```

If you're running X as non-suid root and are interested to find out which program (its name and location) is setting or resetting your gamma/RGBcolors, there's a way to find out [here](https://github.com/jumper149/blugon/issues/25#issuecomment-1238946684).